# Is there a way to set an anchor on a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to be able to set an anchor point for a `JLabel` in the centre, so I can move it around based on that.

Comment: Please tell us more about your current code, your problem, and the specifics of your problem. What exactly do you mean by "anchor point"? Do you mean that if I click on that JLabel, it moves so that it is centered where I click, and then if I drag the center follows the mouse? A [mcve] would also help greatly. This is more than non-compilable code snippets and less than your entire program. Also always show us your attempt to solve this with your question, if possible, as it greatly increases our understanding of just where you may be stuck.

Comment: Also, include much more of what I mentioned above, and none of this: "I've tried googling it, normally I find what I need but not in this case." as it tells us nothing that helps us understand your problem. It only suggests that you're Googling the wrong things, that you've not reduced your problem into small enough steps that are Google search-able.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, this is my first time asking a question. I was hoping I was able to get away with not including code because my current situation only allows me to use my iPad, so it was just a little harder. By anchor point, I mean that if I use label.setLocation(100, 100); it would the anchor point there. So currently the anchor is 0, 0 so typing the above line would put 0, 0 of the JLabel at 100, 100, but I want it to put the canter at 100, 100, hence, asking how to change the anchor point.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels because I'm using Eclipse I've tried using label.set then pressing ctrl+space which bring up all possible options, none of which helped me. I figure if there's a way to do it, it's either not using label.set or it's a little more out of the box.

Comment: FireStrike: It just means using a little extremely basic math. Create your own method, to calculate the center point. You know that JLabel has getSize and getLocation methods, use those and some simple arithmetic to calculate the center point and then place. I'm still not sure where you're stuck.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't think about getSize. As it's a random string of letters each time the size changes, I was hoping there was an easier way instead of having to calculate it based on the amount of letters, which letters, font size, etc. getSize should work nicely. Thanks.

Comment: Or `getPreferredSize()`, but play with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to center a JLabel around a certain point, then all you need is simple mathematics to do this, nothing more.

Assume that you have a JLabel, or any component that we'll name "component", that it's held in a JPanel, or any container that we'll call "container", and assume that there's a mouse Point *on the screen*, say called "mousePoint", then the math is simple as:

```
Point mousePoint = e.getLocationOnScreen();
Point containerLocation = container.getLocationOnScreen();
Dimension componentSize = component.getSize();

int x = mousePoint.x - componentSize.width / 2 - containerLocation.x;
int y = mousePoint.y - componentSize.height / 2 - containerLocation.y;
component.setLocation(x, y);
```

That's it.

For instance, say that you have two JLabels, one with an image, and one with some text on it, then you could add the same MouseListener and MouseMotionListener to both, and this would allow you to drag either by their center points. Here is an example of a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as I mentioned in my comments above:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClickDragLabel extends JPanel {
    public static final String IMG_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/"
            + "Theodore_Comnenus-Ducas_cropped.jpg/133px-Theodore_Comnenus-Ducas_cropped.jpg";
    private static final int PREF_W = 1000;
    private static final int PREF_H = 850;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Some Random Text");

    public ClickDragLabel(Icon icon) {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        imageLabel = new JLabel(icon);

        setLayout(null);
        imageLabel.setSize(imageLabel.getPreferredSize());
        textLabel.setSize(textLabel.getPreferredSize());

        imageLabel.setLocation(250, 250);
        textLabel.setLocation(10, 10);

        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        imageLabel.addMouseListener(myMouse);
        imageLabel.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
        textLabel.addMouseListener(myMouse);
        textLabel.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);

        add(imageLabel);
        add(textLabel);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            center(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            center(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            center(e);
        }

        private void center(MouseEvent e) {
            JComponent component = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            Container container = component.getParent();

            Point mousePoint = e.getLocationOnScreen();
            Point containerLocation = container.getLocationOnScreen();
            Dimension componentSize = component.getSize();

            int x = mousePoint.x - componentSize.width / 2 - containerLocation.x;
            int y = mousePoint.y - componentSize.height / 2 - containerLocation.y;
            component.setLocation(x, y);
            container.repaint();
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Image img = null;
        try {
            URL imgUrl = new URL(IMG_PATH);
            img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);

        ClickDragLabel mainPanel = new ClickDragLabel(icon);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Click-Drag Label");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Having posted this, I would be remiss if I didn't mention the evils of use of null layouts. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one. I use them only for animation, such as above, and for nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to set an anchor on a JLabel?

What you seem to want can be achieved by setting and changing an `EmptyBorder` to the label.

[image] [image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class MovableLabel {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    String anchorString = new String(Character.toChars(9875));
    private JLabel label = new JLabel(anchorString);
    int pad = 200;
    SpinnerNumberModel xModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, pad, 1);
    SpinnerNumberModel yModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, pad, 1);

    MovableLabel() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
        Font font = null;
        for (Font f : fonts) {
            if (f.canDisplayUpTo(anchorString) < 0) {
                font = f.deriveFont(40f);
                break;
            }
        }
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setBorder();
        ui.add(label);

        JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
        ui.add(tb, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                setBorder();
            }
        };

        tb.add(new JLabel("X"));
        JSpinner xSpinner = new JSpinner(xModel);
        xSpinner.addChangeListener(changeListener);
        tb.add(xSpinner);

        tb.add(new JLabel("Y"));
        JSpinner ySpinner = new JSpinner(yModel);
        ySpinner.addChangeListener(changeListener);
        tb.add(ySpinner);
    }

    private void setBorder() {
        int x = xModel.getNumber().intValue();
        int y = yModel.getNumber().intValue();
        EmptyBorder border = new EmptyBorder(x, y, pad - x, pad - y);
        label.setBorder(border);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                MovableLabel o = new MovableLabel();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```